# How to create my own API and connect it to Power apps?

Tags: api, rest, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, powerapps

I really hope you can help me. I have a project to create an app. I will use Power apps, Python and JavaScript. I need to be in it, because I am not. So my first step is create an API, I have decided to use Azure Function I can explain why. It helps connect my Power Apps(frontend, where i am going to use JavaScript) to backend(Python).

So I have absolutely nothing and I have decided to create an API with Azure Functions, the truth is i dont really know how it works. I can connect it with VScode, but the main question how to create own API? I dont need to pay for servis because I have an Azure Functions which is paid. But I dont really understand how API has too look. I have find a lot information but i cant connect it with what I need.

I need to write my own code for API? Like from empty file? Can do it in VS code and connect it with Azure Functions? What has to be in API I mean my own piece of code or something another? Have anyone created his own API in Azure Functions?

thank you for answering my stupid questions

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the Http Trigger in Azure Function if your own API works on HTTP protocol and modify the default [Http Trigger API](https://azurelessons.com/how-to-create-api-with-azure-functions/) Code according to your requirement.

If your API contains 3rd party APIs, you can create the Http client inside the function code for sending HTTP requests on to the available 3rd party APIs in your function code.

There are plenty of articles on connecting the Azure Functions to Power BI Apps where you can write your own AP code using REST API signature following swagger and add that custom API in Power Apps.

Refer to this [article](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/using-azure-functions-in-powerapps/) that provides the use case of connect the Azure Function with custom API Code to Power App, given by [Carlos Aguilar](https://powerapps.microsoft.com/es-es/blog/author/carlosag/).